# enabling/disabling journald ForwardToSyslog option at runtime

Tags: systemd, syslog, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I'm currently working on enabling and disabling `ForwardToSyslog` option in systemd-journald at runtime.

When I set it to "no" -> `ForwardToSyslog=no` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` followed by `systemctl restart systemd-journald` my rsyslog generated files stop receiving info.

My problem:

Reenabling forwarding to syslog by doing: `ForwardToSyslog=yes` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` followed by `systemctl restart systemd-journald` is NOT followed by getting logs inside rsyslog files.

Only newly started systemd services have logs forwarded, but those that were running need to be restarted.

My question:

Is this a bug of a systemd-journald?

Is there a better way to have logs forwarded to syslog than by restarting all of the running services?

EDIT:

I use systemd 230

Comment: You need to tell people what version of systemd this is.  It affects answers.

Comment: It's 230. I've edited the post.

Comment: You should comment on https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2236, it  sounds like you've reproduced a bug that was thought to be fixed in a relatively current version of systemd.

Comment: I have posted on that issue thread that I reproduced the issue with systemd 230 and 232. I hope it will get resolved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [bug in systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2236) that was believed to be fixed.

It sounds like you've reproduced it in a relatively current version of systemd, so you should comment on the bug and follow-up with the developers.

Thanks to @JdeBP for the issue reference.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to reproduce it with the even newer version and then post there if it's not fixed